# gnome-terminal/shell hardening security

Tags: command-line

How to protect gnome-terminal or any shell with a password and maybe something like recaptcha...

It could consult shadowed password database or require user to login like tty.

Maybe it can protect against reverse shell.

Thx

Comment: A shell/interpreter/script can run without a console or even a terminal emulator ... It can run under your graphical session environment ... So, locking the terminal might not be of benefit here ... You can if you want change your shell to a restricted shell e.g. [`rbash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) ... But, the most important thing to do is to be careful and not run arbitrary code/scripts/programs that you don't trust.

Comment: @Raffa Is there any approach relative to mitigate shell/sudo "breaches" ?? maybe specific pam (pluggable authenticatioon module), lsm, firejail or anything else ...

Comment: You need shells ... Shells are what enable you to interact with the kernel and they come in variety of shapes including your DE interface which is actually a shell called [`gnome-shell`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell) ... User account login-shells are already securely authenticated under the user login authentication system ... Moreover, the concept of "reverse shell" is not actually exclusively a bad/evil thing but rather a common needed feature ... See for example [SSH reverse shells](https://moreillon.medium.com/ssh-reverse-shells-5094d9be2094) ... Your approach is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need shells to make use of your Ubuntu OS  ... Shells are what enable you to interact with the kernel and they come in variety of shapes including your DE interface which is actually a shell called [`gnome-shell`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell) ... User account login-shells are already securely authenticated under the user login authentication system ... Moreover, the concept of "*reverse shell*" is not actually exclusively a bad/evil thing but rather a common needed feature that some applications implement ... See for example [SSH reverse tunnels/shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46235).

Actually, your approach is not correct ... A shell/interpreter/script can run without a console or even a terminal emulator ... It can run under your graphical session environment ... So, locking the terminal might not be of benefit here ... You can if you want change your shell to a restricted shell e.g. [`rbash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) ... But, the most important thing to do is to be careful and not run arbitrary code/scripts/programs that you don't trust.

Comment: Is gnome-remote-desktop a shell? My idead is try to avoid autorun, autoplay, bots, arbitrary code, even spread a malware, because shell has high availability and any user has rx permissions on the system over the programs (like sudo, chroot and setuid programs) as defined on PATH variable into /etc/environment. If i run a code with regular user in a shell comunicating a server owned root, isnt a breach on the other side? Escalation privileges attempts could be possible in theory ...

Comment: @LuizCarlos I see what you mean but, AFAIK I don't see how it might be possible the way you describe ... Other users however might know something that I don't and in that case somebody will post an answer hopefully with a solution to achieve what you want  ... I wouldn't be optimistic though :-)